# update value in python dictionary by adding a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, while-loop

I want to make a program that adds a name in the dictionary if it doesn't exist already and count the times it is given as input. My code works, however, it doesn't add 1 when it iterates.

```
namelist = {}

def namen():
    while True:
        word = input('Vul een naam in: ')
        if word == '':
            break
        else:
            for name in namelist:
                if word == name:
                    namelist[word] += 1
                # else wasn't properly indented earlier
                else:
                    namelist[word] = 1


print(namen())

print(namelist)
```

Comment: your innermost `else` statement is not properly indented, it is within the innermost `if` and not the `for`

Comment: For name in namelist translates to: for value in values, but you use keys as an indicator. Try calling for on dict.keys instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one said anything about the has_key method of dictionaries, which is in my opinion the standard way to to this:

```
namelist = {}

def namen():
    while True:
        word = input('Vul een naam in: ')
        if word == '':
            break
        else:
            if namelist.has_key(word):
                namelist[word] += 1
            else:
                namelist[word] = 1

print(namen())

print(namelist)
```

Comment: I think `if word in namelist` is more idiomatic (and `dict.has_key()` was removed from Python 3)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `dict.get` method instead to provide a default value to a new entry to the dict:

```
namelist = {}

def namen():
    while True:
        word = input('Vul een naam in: ')
        if word == '':
            break
        else:
            for name in namelist:
                if word == name:
                    namelist[word] = namelist.get(word, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your check is incorrect, you need `if` rather than `for` to see if the key exists, then you can remove the inner if statement

```
   if name in namelist:
        namelist[word] += 1
    else:
        namelist[word] = 1
```

Comment: I don't think your second suggestion will work: `+=` can't be used on the return value of `setdefault()`.

Comment: @wjt - Ah you're right, slow day for me today, I've just removed it since the effort involved in making that work would be less useful than just the simple if statement

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
namelist = {}

def namen():
    while True:
        word = input('Vul een naam in: ')
        if word == '':
            break
        else:
            try:
                namelist[word] += 1
            except:
                namelist[word] = 1

print(namen())

print(namelist)
```